# Is there a way to customize/relocate nav sphere?

Tags: interface, sculpting, navigation

I am currently running Blender 2.9 (but this would apply to 2.8 as well). In the upper right corner is a nav sphere, but it may be called something else. I have searched for weeks looking for an answer. I would like to move it from top-right to middle-left of the interface. My purpose is to allow me to model on my Lenovo 2 in 1 in tablet mode. This "sphere" will keep my right hand free for editing and sculpting using bamboo pen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The thing is called the *3D Viewport Axis* and you can use preferences to change its form from the one you've shown called *Interactive Navigation*.  You can change it to a simpler form called *Simple Axis* or you can turn it off completely.  You can change its size and how bright it is compared to the rest of the 3D viewport.

[image: Preference showing viewport settings with 3D viewport axis picker]

The one thing that you can't do, unfortunately, is change where it is located.